# Iterate array in array and echo strings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a problem listed below:

I handle 3 arrays from client side. They always have random length, but by their length they are equal to each other. Then I use $summary_array to gather all data and iterate through.

Example:

```
$country = (1,2,3);
$city = (4,5,6);
$sightseen = (7,8,9);

$summary_array = ($country, $city, $sightseen);
```

OR

```
$country = (1,2,3,4);
$city = (1,3,4,5);
$sightseen = (5,2,9,4);

$summary_array = ($country, $city, $sightseen);
```

And now I need to iterate through these arrays:

```
foreach($summary_array as $value) {
    //...
}
```

And I need to get in the output:

```
1 : 1 2 3
2 : 4 5 6
3 : 7 8 9
```

OR

```
1 : 1 2 3 4
2 : 1 3 4 5
3 : 5 2 9 4
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong!!!!

I receive my values from client side like this:

$country = (1, 2, 3);
$city = (4, 5, 6);
$sightseen = (7, 8, 9);

So I need to obtain values which contain one value from each other:

0: 1  4  7
1: 2  5  8
2: 3  6  9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides that you missed the keyword `array`in every array declaration, you can simply [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) each array in every iteration like this:

```
foreach($summary_array as $k => $value) {
    echo ($k+1) . " : " . implode(" ", $value) . "<br>";
}
```

output:

```
1 : 1 2 3  //1 : 1 2 3 4
2 : 4 5 6  //2 : 1 3 4 5
3 : 7 8 9  //3 : 5 2 9 4
```

**EDIT:**

To rotate your array, just simply use this before your foreach loop:

```
$summary_array = call_user_func_array("array_map", array(NULL, $country, $city, $sightseen));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is one more question))

How I can implement a SQL query from data I got?

for example:
 foreach( $option as $k => $value) {
INSERT INTO table name (country_id, city_id, sightseen_id) VALUES ($country, $city, $sightseen);

Exatly I mean 3 query from arrays:

INSERT INTO table name (country_id, city_id, sightseen_id) VALUES (1, 4, 7);

INSERT INTO table name (country_id, city_id, sightseen_id) VALUES (2, 5, 8);

INSERT INTO table name (country_id, city_id, sightseen_id) VALUES (3, 6, 9);

???

Comment: @user2642396 Just implode  the value in the string like this: `echo $sql = "INSERT INTO table name (country_id, city_id, sightseen_id) VALUES (" . implode(", ", $value) . ")";` (<- Use this in the foreach loop)

Comment: Sorry))) One more)))

And what if I need to perform a select?
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE country_id=$A AND city_id=$B AND sightseen_id=$C;

???

Comment: @user2642396 I think this goes slowly a bit too broad, the comment section is not there for answering questions. Please try at least a few times and if you have a new problem you can ask a new question.